# Chrome browser versus Chrome on Google TV

Tags: google-chrome, google-tv

Is Chrome on Google TV different than Chrome that I use on my desktop?
If yes, what is the difference?

I ask this question since I noticed that my yahoo page loads differently on my Chrome desktop than Chrome on Google TV.

Thank you for your help.
Yves

Answer (score 0):

> **Is the Google TV browser different than the one on my personal computer?
> Can I access the same content?**
>
> The browser on Google TV is basically the Linux version of Google Chrome 11. While the user > interface is modified slightly for the TV form factor, most of the rendering and web
> platform capabilities are consistent with desktop versions of Google Chrome and you will
> receive the latest updates automatically.

From here:
https://developers.google.com/tv/faq#browserdifference

Found by searching:
https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+google+tv+vs+chrome+desktop